# Generating unique fixed length strings

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I need to generate unique non-sequential IDs of specified length. I've looked up some implementations of Feistel ciphers but I don't understand why exactly specific numbers are chosen and how do they affect output. Basically, I need a function `int pseudo_encrypt(int seed, int max)` that  produces unique result less than max for each seed less than max.

UPD: It turns out it's called 'format-preserving encryption'. I've tried AES CTR mode but the problem is the 'length' is specified in bytes. So if `max` is greater than 255 the cipher will produce a result between 0 and 65535. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: You want [format preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). For example you could use FFX mode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing into right direction, but see update.

Comment: Don't use CTR mode when you want to preserve the format. CTR needs a unique per-message value, called a nonce. Without that nonce (which you can't use with format preserving encryption) it loses all security. FFX mode is complicated, but I don't anything that's much simpler and still secure.

Comment: @CodesInChaos security is not required for this particular case. it's just a routine to generate ids from auto-incrementing database sequence

Comment: CTR with fixed nonce is equivalent to xoring the seed with a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cipher is correct.  Since a cipher is reversible, each seed number will encrypt to a unique cyphered value and can be decrypted back to the original value.

To generate your required sequence of unique numbers, you encrypt seeds 0, 1, 2, 3, ... for as many unique numbers as you require.

Your major problem is likely the value of max you need.  For max = (2^64) - 1 then use DES in ECB mode with a fixed key.  For max = (2^128) - 1 use AES in ECB mode with a fixed key.  Different keys give a different mapping from plaintext to cyphertext, so you need to keep using the same key to avoid duplicates.

If your max is a different size, then you will have to do more work.  Basically you need a block cipher with the same block size as your value of max, measured in bits.  You can construct your own Feistel cipher with the appropriate block size, or else you can use [Hasty Pudding cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher), which allows any reasonable block size you want.